# chartjs unlimited x axis labels

Tags: chart.js

i have a chart that fills itself with values, however currently i am limited on how many values i can display by the amount of label values i insert. 
`$scope.AxirsLabels = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];`
for example with the above label value i can only display 10 different values on the chart.
is it possible to set an unlimited amount of values based on the values of data?
each data value is an integer like 10 or 20 etc.
[image: example chart]

everytime the user clicks a button values are added to the data of the chart and the X axis needs to adjust.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using the function i use for adding data to the chart for the label values as well. this adds label values based on the amount of data values there are.
`$scope.AxirsLabels = getDataProp('values');`
[image: correct chart labels based on data values]